# Unmet dependencies while trying to install pulseeffects

Tags: drivers, software-installation, pulseaudio, pip

I downloaded the .zip file from GitHub so I could have the most recent version but, when I try to run `./pulseeffects`, it keeps coming up with modules that aren't found. numpy was the first one which I installed with pip. Now it can't find scipy so I tried to install it the same way to no effect. I'm running Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 if that makes a difference.

```
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pulseeffects", line 4, in <module>
    from PulseEffects.application import Application
  File "/home/amolith/Downloads/Programs/pulseeffects-master/PulseEffects/application.py", line 18, in <module>
    from PulseEffects.sink_input_effects import SinkInputEffects
  File "/home/amolith/Downloads/Programs/pulseeffects-master/PulseEffects/sink_input_effects.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
ImportError: No module named 'scipy'
```

Answer (score 0):

Carefully reading the README.MD file from github, there are several dependancies:

```
Required libraries:

    Python 3
    Python configparser (Python versions higher than 3.5.0 come with it. There is no need to install a separate package)
    PyGobject 3
    Python Cairo
    Python Numpy
    Python Scipy (0.18 or above)
    Gtk 3.18 or above
    Gstreamer, Gstreamer Plugins Good, Gstreamer Plugins Bad and Gstreamer Python (Since version 1.4.3 Pulseeffects needs Gstreamer 1.12 or above)
    swh-plugins from Ladspa
```

Comment: I'm saying that I don't know how to install Scipy in a way that pulseeffects will recognise it. I already had Numpy when I tried to install it but it didn't recognise that I had it until I install it using pip. When I install Scipy using pip, it didn't recognise it.

Comment: @Amolith [https://askubuntu.com/questions/868599/how-to-install-scipy-and-numpy-on-ubuntu-16-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868599/how-to-install-scipy-and-numpy-on-ubuntu-16-04), you may have to install `python3-pip`

Comment: I ran all of the commands in that answer and none of them worked. I'll paste the output from running `sudo ./pulseeffects`.